# retrieving certain values from ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: java, arraylist

i have this arrayalist:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactListad
```

it contains:

```
[{emailAddress=samir, lastName=samir, contactId=4, phoneNumber=6449494, firstName=samir, homeAddress=paris}, {emailAddress=, lastName=, contactId=6, phoneNumber=, firstName=Rashad, homeAddress=las vegas}, {emailAddress=, lastName=, contactId=9, phoneNumber=, firstName=joe, homeAddress=paris}]
```

My question iy ifs how can i get the values and store them in another arraylist i want to specify to store only the values having a certain homeAddress equals paris for example.
i hope my question is clear enough

for example if i specify the homeAddress to be paris, i want the output to be an arraylist containing

```
[{emailAddress=samir, lastName=samir, contactId=4, phoneNumber=6449494, firstName=samir,     
homeAddress=paris},{emailAddress=, lastName=, contactId=9, phoneNumber=, firstName=joe,    
homeAddress=paris}]
```

so without the hasmap that has homeAddress equals las vegas

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Can you share the output you're trying to get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> newArray = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for(HashMap<String, String> hm : contactListad){
    String val = hm.get("homeAddress");
    if("paris".equals(val)){
        newArray.add(hm);
    }

}
```

now you have what you want in `newArray`

Comment: +1.But bad practice to name a variable as `newArray` which is actually a list.

Comment: @TAsk you are 100% right, but i just gave him an example

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(HashMap<String, String> hashMap : contactListad) {
        String homeAdress = hashMap.get("homeAdress");
        if (homeAdress.equals("Paris")) {
            //write your code here
        }
    }
```

Comment: no i did not. i had the edit window open and did not see your answer. and hey - what should the solution look like other than the 2 answers posted ?? anyway thanks for the downvote